# Invalid Column Name on Existing Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to trouble shoot this issue for a bit, but can't seem to figure out what's going on. I keep getting an error that says `invalid column name 'Section_1'`. I know `Section_1` exists, but cant seem to track down the issue that's causing this error. Here is a portion of my code, if more is needed I can add to it:

EDIT:

```
 DECLARE @NewCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @qry AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @NewCols = STUFF((SELECT distinct
                        ',' +
                        QUOTENAME([Section_1])
                FROM [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @qry =
'INSERT INTO [DBO].ATT_tbl_AS (

    Bill_Date
    ,MTN
    ,User_Name
    ,Adjustments_To_Previous_Balance
    ,FAN_Invoice_Previous_Balance
    ,FAN_Invoice_Past_Due
    ,FAN_Invoice_Amount_Due
    ,FAN_Invoice_Total_Current_Charges
    ,FAN_Invoice_Total_Payments

    )


Select

    Query_Selection.[ Bill_Date]
    ,Query_Selection.[Wireless Number]
    ,Query_Selection.[User Name] 
    ,Query_Selection.[Adjustments To Previous Balance]
    ,Query_Selection.[Previous Balance]
    ,Query_Selection.[Remaining (Past Due) Balance]
    ,Query_Selection.[TOTAL AMOUNT DUE]
    ,Query_Selection.[Total Current Charges]
    ,Query_Selection.[Total Payments]


    FROM( 



        Select  [Bill_Date],  [Wireless Number], [User Name],' + @NewCols +'
    From 
        (
            Select 
                  [Bill_Date], [Wireless Number], [User Name],  [Amount] as SumOfAmount
                 From [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import]
                 Where [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import].[Section ID] = ''IRA'' AND [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import].[Section_1] IS Not Null
                 ) t
                 PIVOT 
                 (
                 SUM(SumOfAmount)
                    FOR [Section_1] IN (' + @NewCols + ')
                    ) p 


    ) as Query_Selection'


    execute (@qry)
```

EDIT: Added the Print View as well.

```
 DECLARE @NewCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @qry AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT @NewCols = STUFF((SELECT distinct
                            ',' +
                            QUOTENAME([Section_1])
                    FROM [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
                ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ,1,1,'')

    SET @qry =
    'INSERT INTO [DBO].ATT_tbl_AS (

        Bill_Date
        ,MTN
        ,User_Name
        ,Adjustments_To_Previous_Balance
        ,FAN_Invoice_Previous_Balance
        ,FAN_Invoice_Past_Due
        ,FAN_Invoice_Amount_Due
        ,FAN_Invoice_Total_Current_Charges
        ,FAN_Invoice_Total_Payments

        )


    Select

        Query_Selection.[ Bill_Date]
        ,Query_Selection.[Wireless Number]
        ,Query_Selection.[User Name] 
        ,Query_Selection.[Adjustments To Previous Balance]
        ,Query_Selection.[Previous Balance]
        ,Query_Selection.[Remaining (Past Due) Balance]
        ,Query_Selection.[TOTAL AMOUNT DUE]
        ,Query_Selection.[Total Current Charges]
        ,Query_Selection.[Total Payments]


        FROM( 



            Select  [Bill_Date],  [Wireless Number], [User Name],[Adjustments to Previous Balance],[Previous Balance],[Remaining (Past Due) Balance],[TOTAL AMOUNT DUE],[Total Current Charges],[Total Payments]
        From 
            (
                Select 
                      [Bill_Date], [Wireless Number], [User Name],  [Amount] as SumOfAmount
                     From [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import]
                     Where [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import].[Section ID] = ''IRA'' AND [dbo].[Raw_Data_Import].[Section_1] IS Not Null
                     ) t
                     PIVOT 
                     (
                     SUM(SumOfAmount)
                        FOR [Section_1] IN ([Adjustments to Previous Balance],[Previous Balance],[Remaining (Past Due) Balance],[TOTAL AMOUNT DUE],[Total Current Charges],[Total Payments])
                        ) p 


        ) as Query_Selection'


        execute (@qry)
```

`FOR [Section_1] IN (' + @NewCols + ')` is the portion throwing the error, but not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you actually assigning a string value to `@qry` or running it just like that?

Comment: yes I am, I'll go ahead and post the rest of my query to stop any confusion

Comment: Well if you're running it like that then it's going to error. It's hard to know since you do have quote marks and a variable and an `execute`. At minimum you need `declare @qry nvarchar(max) = '...`

Comment: I have added the rest of the query, everything you see now is what I'm running

Comment: Looks like you still missing the opening quote mark around the query string.

Comment: That was a typo when I added the edit, I actually fixed that just a second ago. You should see the update now

Comment: I noticed. Can you do `print @qry` before trying to execute?

Comment: Space inside `[ Bill_Date]` will need correcting...

Comment: Just added the print view version to the question

Comment: Not sure why you're even using dynamic sql when the outermost query lists out the column explicity. Trying to run that expanded query should give the same error though.

Comment: I'm trying to convert this query from one I had in an Access database. In Access you can you a `Transform` which does things dynamically. This does not exist in SQL Server to my knowledge, so I'm trying to put this together the best I can lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not listing `Section_1` in `t`'s select list. I think that's your problem.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks!